# Meteor Package add global asset

Tags: javascript, meteor

To add an asset from meteor package what you need to do is:

```
api.add_files(['s.json'], 'server', {isAsset: true});
```

Now you can call this asset by

```
Assets.getText("s.json");
```

But the problem is this only works in the package the asset is added to.

Is there a way to add asset so that you can get this asset from other package as well?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You need to export the asset text:

In a file (somefile.js)

```
AssetData = Assets.getText("s.json");
```

in your package.js

```
api.add_files(['some.js', 'files.json'], 'server');
api.export("AssetData", ["server"]);
```

Then in your other package

package.js

```
api.use("<name of other package>");
```

Then you can use `AssetData` anywhere in that package on the server side.